# Pass arguments into array of observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using a `forkJoin` of observables but I'm having troubles to pass arguments in my observables. Lines of code worth a thousand words:

```
for(var key in pdfObjects){
    let pdf = {pdfObjects[key]};
    observables.push(new Observable(observer => {
        this.createPDF(pdf).subscribe((pdfFile) => {
            // Do something with my pdfFile
            observer.complete();
        })
    })
}
Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
    (next) => {},
    (error) => {},
    (completed) => {
        console.log('completed');
    }
);
```

(I have simplified the code for better clarity)

As you can see here, the problem is that when the code executes the observables, the `pdf` variable is equal to the last `pdfObjects` instead of being a different variable for each observable.

The question is how can I 'pass' and 'copy' my `pdf` variable so it's a diffent one for each observable?

Comment: Did you mean to surround the value with brackets in the let, creating a new object with a key of 'pdfObjects', or is that a typo when simplifying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the `next` method instead of the `complete` one:

```
observables.push(new Observable(observer => {
  this.createPDF(pdf).subscribe((pdfFile) => {
    // Do something with my pdfFile
    observer.next(pdf); // <-----
  });
})
```

**Edit**

Your problem is related to the use of closures within loops.

You could break with a method:

```
createObservable(pdf:any) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.createPDF(pdf).subscribe((pdfFile) => {
      // Do something with my pdfFile
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
}

otherMethod() {
  for(var key in pdfObjects){
    let pdf = {pdfObjects[key]};
    observables.push(this.createObservable(pdf));
  }
  (...)
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/P4BfwnA1HEw7KU4i3RbN?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve the problem here... `observer.next()` will simply return the pdf value in the `subscribe` of the `forkJoin`! What I need is that each observable has its own `pdf` variable as it argument.

Comment: I think that your problem is related to the use of closures within loops. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Will the observables have a different `pdf` argument? The problem I see is that you're pushing the function with a `pdf` reference and that reference will change (it will be equal to the last pdfObjects item) when it will be executed by the `forkJoin`.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: In fact, in this case, the variable wouldn't be bound to the variable outside the inner function (your problem). I added a plunkr in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Thierry is right, here's an example to show what's going on ([***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/by2cz7nc/4/))

```
var pdfObjects = {
  a: 'Object A',
  b: 'Object B',
  c: 'Object C'
};

for(let key in pdfObjects) {
  let pdf = pdfObjects[key];
  function createObservable(p) {
    console.log('createObservable:', p, pdf, key);
    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
      console.log('createObservable.create:', p, pdf, key);
      observer.onNext({ p: p, pdf: pdf, key: key});
      observer.onCompleted();
    });
  }
  observables.push(createObservable(pdf));
}
```

Result:

```
createObservable: Object A Object A a
createObservable: Object B Object B b
createObservable: Object C Object C c
createObservable.create: Object A Object C c
createObservable.create: Object B Object C c
createObservable.create: Object C Object C c
```

When `createObservable` is called, each value is as you would expect.  But when you subscribe to your observables, the anonymous function that takes `observer` is called by RxJs and is using the current values for `pdf` and `key` which are what they were the last time through the loop.  But because you're creating a function, there's a new scope and the argument 'p' in that scope is the value the function was called with.